# Pipenv Pipfile - installing package from private repo

Tags: environment-variables, pipenv, pipfile

I'm trying to install a package via Pipfile from a private repo.

Using the following syntax, VScode is asking for a password (in console it is locking forever), although my token is exported to my env variables:

```
[packages]
pack1 = {editable = true, git = "https://${ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com/.../pack1.git"}
```

Using the ACCESS_TOKEN directly it works like expected:

```
[packages]
pack1 = {editable = true, git = "https://myToken@github.com/.../pack1.git"}
```

Using pipenv install command works also fine with my environment variable (ACCESS_TOKEN):

```
pipenv install -e git+https://${ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com/.../pack1.git
```

Do you have any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly did you set the env var `ACCESS_TOKEN`? How exactly did you export it? VS Code just uses your OS's underlying terminal, so if the terminal config has an exported ACCESS_TOKEN, so VS Code should be able to find it.

Comment: It is also not clear what "*it is locking forever*" means. If the git URL is not valid, the  `pipenv install` command would eventually fail (might take some time, but certainly not "forever").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely due to your `pipenv` version not supporting env-var expansion in the requirements (packages) section ([see this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3516)). This was fixed in `pipenv` version [2020.11.15](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/releases/tag/v2020.11.15).

I had this exact problem with an older version and indeed upgrading `pipenv` to `2020.11.15` made it work.